# local_import function does not work

Tags: python, apache, wsgi, web2py, web2py-modules

local_import function randomly does not import my modules from modules
directory. The Error is:

> ImportError: No module named testapp.modules.mymodule

I have this problem when i use web2py with apache (with wsgi). I have no problem when i run locally with "python web2py.py" command.

Any suggestion?

Comment: can you say something abour your filesystem structure ? do you have ____init____.py files in the subfolders ?

Comment: i did not understand what you mean by "filesystem structre". I have __init__.py in all subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.96.1, `local_import()` has been deprecated. You should be able to do:

```
import mymodule
```

and it will look in your application's /modules folder before checking sys.path.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question :)
I started using mod_proxy and everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Add `testapp` to your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I do not want to add my modules globally.

Comment: It's not neccesary to add it globally, you can make that change in the config file you provide to mod_wsgi

Comment: All applications in web2py will see the modules.

Comment: Then, add "modules" in the "____init____.py" file.

Comment: I have ____init____.py in modules directory. You mean add modules to ____init____.py?

Comment: Yes. See my answer under "Alternative implementations of python/setuptools entry points (extensions) in other languages/applications", where I show how to add modules.